# Error in mediate - unused arguments

Tags: r, syntax-error, statistics-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
model.xy <- lm(Y ~  X, Htest)

model.mx <- lm(M  ~  X, Htest)

model.yxm <- lm(Y   ~  X + M, Htest)
```

These regressions are doing fine (also summary view) but then when I want to check for mediation effect the code is getting an error.

```
results <- mediate(model.mx, model.yxm, treat='X', mediator='M', boot=TRUE, sims=500)
```

The code above used to work last week and now I keep getting:

Error in mediate(model.mx, model.yxm, treat = "X", mediator = "M", boot = TRUE,  : 
  unused arguments (treat = "X", mediator = "M", boot = TRUE, sims = 500)

Can someone please tell me what might be wrong? I have the required packages and all variables exist and I have no typos.. it really worked last week. I am really confused.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting R -- the `mediate` function probably got overwritten somewhere along the way.